C Code compiled on Raspbian Bookworm won't run on Buster
When I compile code on a Raspberry Pi running the latest Bookworm release, it won't run on a Raspberry Pi with Buster.  It returns cannot execute binary file: Exec format error. Why?
Compile on Bookworm:
pi@Bookworm:~ $ gcc -o hello_world hello_world.c
pi@Bookworm:~ $ ./hello_world 
Hello world!
pi@Bookworm:~ $ scp hello_world pi@Buster.local:/home/pi/

pi@Bookworm~ $ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 12 \n \l
pi@WBookworm:~ $ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0

Then run it on Buster:
pi@Buster:~ $ ./hello_world 
-bash: ./hello_world: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

pi@Buster:~ $ cat /etc/issue
Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 \n \l
pi@Buster:~ $ gcc --version
gcc (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

And just in case the file was corrupted in scp transit, I copied the same file back to Bookworm over scp as hello_world_back and it ran just fine.
$ ./hello_world_back
Hello world!


Is one a 64bit install and one a 32bit install?  What does file say about your program?

Running uname -a on both systems would also be useful for debugging stuff like this.

$ file hello_world
hello_world: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, BuildID[sha1]=6768f7173f6b38a4a28c3ee13295a5928f8caac7, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, not stripped

Buster: $ uname -a
Linux Woodley-BLE-Xcvr 4.19.57-v7+ #1244 SMP Thu Jul 4 18:45:25 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux, Bookworm: $ uname -a
Linux Woodley-CTLR-ENTRY 6.6.20+rpt-rpi-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.6.20-1+rpt1 (2024-03-07) aarch64 GNU/Linux

The problem is that the Buster install is 32-bit Raspbian (the default for Buster), and the Bookworm install is 64-bit Raspbian (the new preferred image).  When you compile on a 64-bit machine, it makes a 64-bit compiled binary.  And you cannot run a 64-bit program on a 32-bit Raspbian OS, even if the underlying hardware has a 64-bit capable processor (which all 3B+ and higher including my Buster install do).
Bottom line:  binary images created with gcc cannot be run on 32-bit Linux if compiled on 64-bit Linux unless you go to the extra effort to create a 32-bin binary.
